Corresponding value for addRequirement method parameter in AutoCAD 2025 .Net API
I have been developing .Net plugins for AutoCAD for many years and one of the routines I have always used is to take a Snapshot of an object in CAD. A code that worked very well until AutoCAD 2024 was this...
static public Bitmap CreateSnapshot(Entity ent, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    Manager manager = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.GraphicsManager;

    KernelDescriptor descriptor = new KernelDescriptor();

    descriptor.addRequirement(Autodesk.AutoCAD.UniqueString.Intern("3D Drawing"));
    GraphicsKernel m_pGraphicsKernel = Manager.AcquireGraphicsKernel(descriptor);
    Device device = manager.CreateAutoCADOffScreenDevice(m_pGraphicsKernel);
    Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsSystem.Model model = manager.CreateAutoCADModel(m_pGraphicsKernel);

    using (device) {
      device.OnSize(new System.Drawing.Size(width, height));
      using (model) {

        Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsSystem.View view = new Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsSystem.View();
        Extents3d ext = ent.GeometricExtents;
        double width2 = ext.MaxPoint.X - ext.MinPoint.X;
        double height2 = ext.MaxPoint.Y - ext.MinPoint.Y;
        device.Add(view);
        view.Add(ent, model);
        try {
          view.SetView(view.Position, view.Target, view.UpVector, width2, height2);
          view.ZoomExtents(ext.MinPoint, ext.MaxPoint);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { Debug.Print(ex.Message); };
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        bmp = view.GetSnapshot(rect);


      }
    }
    return bmp;
  }

But now in AutoCAD 2025 according to the documentation the addRequirement method receives a parameter of type 'System::UInt64' and no longer 'Autodesk.AutoCAD.UniqueString'. The same documentation says nothing about what are the corresponding values ​​in 'System::UInt64' for the 4 UniqueString variations we had before, they are:

"2D Drawing"
"3D Drawing"
"3D2 Drawing"
"RapidRTRendering3D"

If you check in the documentation provided by Autodesk looks like they forgot to update information about the parameter of this method:
https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2025/ENU/?guid=OARX-ManagedRefGuide-Autodesk_AutoCAD_GraphicsSystem_KernelDescriptor_addRequirement_System__UInt64
I tried several ways to convert a "3D Drawing" string to UInt64 or ulong and nothing worked.
I spent half the sole of my shoe wandering around forums of the old continent looking for the answer, could someone help me save the other half?

I don’t use .NET, but in C++, I see that these values are a hashed uint64_t value
Function AcUniqueString:: Intern computes the hash
static constexpr const value drawing2D()          { return Intern(L"2D Drawing"); }
static constexpr const value drawing3D()          { return Intern(L"3D Drawing"); }
static constexpr const value drawing3D2()         { return Intern(L"3D Drawing2"); }
static constexpr const value selection3D()        { return Intern(L"3D Selection"); }
static constexpr const value rapidRTRendering3D() { return Intern(L"RapidRT Rendering"); }
evaluates to
7683018590669162011
2214423277979634346
6597414901591013976
3660767239623169546
1103457441999370423
maybe there's a new enum?
edit: using IL spy, I see .NET's KernelDescriptor has these as static members
test function
static void AcRxPyApp_idoit(void)
{
    acutPrintf(std::format(L"{},{},{},{},{}",
        AcGsKernelDescriptor::k2DDrawing,
        AcGsKernelDescriptor::k3DDrawing,
        AcGsKernelDescriptor::k3DDrawing2,
        AcGsKernelDescriptor::k3DSelection,
        AcGsKernelDescriptor::k3DRapidRTRendering).c_str());
}


I think I just came across the same issue.
Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsSystem.KernelDescriptor has everything you might need as static ulong's.
var descriptor = new _AcGs.KernelDescriptor();
descriptor.addRequirement(_AcGs.KernelDescriptor.Drawing3D);

